# Rails 3.1: How do I access the API documentation from within Eclipse/Aptana Studio 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to access Rails 3.1 documentation from within Eclipse/Aptana Studio 3.0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can access the Rails 3.1 docs/api from Eclipse/Aptana Studio without doing a little work.

You can download a local copy of the docs and run from your machine. I found downloadable docs from: http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/11/15/download-rails-3-1-1-rdoc-api/

I downloaded this tar ball, unzipped and moved it to my root Apache directory (so that it was at localhost/rails311). Then, in Aptana, I can use the Web Browser view to load this up and access it from within the IDE ... sort of :).

It's a bit of a workaround/hack but it does get you the API/Docs locally and usable in your IDE.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Here is something I just found out: highlighting a word then doing the following: right clicking->Commands->Rails->documentation for word seems to show the documentation for that particular word.

Comment: Hey, nice! I hadn't noticed that in the Commands for Rails. Only 'drag' is that it does go to an online site (i.e., might not work if your offline while working ... and that might not be a huge issue, of course!). Thanks for posting back that tip!